# mock data for this.$el for unit this with karma

Tags: unit-testing, if-statement, vue.js, karma-jasmine

I want to create a unit test for the following vuejs method with Karma.

```
    removeClass(e) {
        if (!this.$el.contains(e.target)) {
            this.isActive = false;
        }
    }
```

How can I mock the data from the if statement to get the return back?

```
   describe('removeClass()', () => {
        it('should return false', () => {
            vm.removeClass();
            expect(vm.isActive).toBe(false);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with:

```
spyOn(vm.$el, 'contains').and.returnValue(false);
```